# How to detect openvino devices in cpp code

Tags: c++, openvino

I am using OpenVINO 2019 and I need to detect the CPU and VPU for my project. Previously in 2018 version I had used some API, but now they are missing in new version.

So what is the proper way to detect openvino devices in a cpp code.

Comment: A quick search brings me to http://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_IE_DG_InferenceEngine_QueryAPI.html Is this the API that was removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hello query device sample in the below path.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino_\inference_engine\samples\hello_query_device**

It queries Inference Engine devices and prints their metrics and default configuration values. The sample shows how to use Query Device API feature.

> **NOTE:** This topic describes usage of C++ implementation of the Query Device Sample. 
>   For the Python* implementation, refer to Hello Query Device Python* Sample

### Running

To see quired information, run the following:

```sh
./hello_query_device
```

### Sample Output

The application prints all available devices with their supported metrics and default values for configuration parameters:

```
Available devices: 
    Device: CPU
    Metrics: 
        AVAILABLE_DEVICES : [ 0 ]
        SUPPORTED_METRICS : [ AVAILABLE_DEVICES SUPPORTED_METRICS FULL_DEVICE_NAME OPTIMIZATION_CAPABILITIES SUPPORTED_CONFIG_KEYS RANGE_FOR_ASYNC_INFER_REQUESTS RANGE_FOR_STREAMS ]
        FULL_DEVICE_NAME : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
        OPTIMIZATION_CAPABILITIES : [ WINOGRAD FP32 INT8 BIN ]
        SUPPORTED_CONFIG_KEYS : [ CPU_BIND_THREAD CPU_THREADS_NUM CPU_THROUGHPUT_STREAMS DUMP_EXEC_GRAPH_AS_DOT DYN_BATCH_ENABLED DYN_BATCH_LIMIT EXCLUSIVE_ASYNC_REQUESTS PERF_COUNT ]
        ...
    Default values for device configuration keys: 
        CPU_BIND_THREAD : YES
        CPU_THREADS_NUM : 0
        CPU_THROUGHPUT_STREAMS : 1
        DUMP_EXEC_GRAPH_AS_DOT : ""
        DYN_BATCH_ENABLED : NO
        DYN_BATCH_LIMIT : 0
        EXCLUSIVE_ASYNC_REQUESTS : NO
        PERF_COUNT : NO

    Device: FPGA
    Metrics: 
        AVAILABLE_DEVICES : [ 0 ]
        SUPPORTED_METRICS : [ AVAILABLE_DEVICES SUPPORTED_METRICS SUPPORTED_CONFIG_KEYS FULL_DEVICE_NAME OPTIMIZATION_CAPABILITIES RANGE_FOR_ASYNC_INFER_REQUESTS ]
        SUPPORTED_CONFIG_KEYS : [ DEVICE_ID PERF_COUNT EXCLUSIVE_ASYNC_REQUESTS DLIA_IO_TRANSFORMATIONS_NATIVE DLIA_ARCH_ROOT_DIR DLIA_PERF_ESTIMATION ]
        FULL_DEVICE_NAME : a10gx_2ddr : Intel Vision Accelerator Design with Intel Arria 10 FPGA (acla10_1150_sg10)
        OPTIMIZATION_CAPABILITIES : [ FP16 ]
        RANGE_FOR_ASYNC_INFER_REQUESTS : { 2, 5, 1 }
    Default values for device configuration keys: 
        DEVICE_ID : [ 0 ]
        PERF_COUNT : true
        EXCLUSIVE_ASYNC_REQUESTS : false
        DLIA_IO_TRANSFORMATIONS_NATIVE : false
        DLIA_PERF_ESTIMATION : true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ExecutableNetworkInternal::Ptr clDNNEngine::LoadExeNetworkImpl(InferenceEngine::ICNNNetwork &network,
                                                               const std::map<std::string, std::string> &config) {
    auto specifiedDevice = network.getTargetDevice();
    auto supportedDevice = InferenceEngine::TargetDevice::eGPU;
    if (specifiedDevice != InferenceEngine::TargetDevice::eDefault && specifiedDevice != supportedDevice) {
        THROW_IE_EXCEPTION << "The plugin doesn't support target device: " << getDeviceName(specifiedDevice) << ".\n" <<
                           "Supported target device: " << getDeviceName(supportedDevice);
    }
```